# How to I preset a repository section in a gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle

I would like to define a plugin which sets the `repositories{...}` section in a gradle project to use our approved proxies and repos, and removes the need to define them in every project. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it e.g. in the following way:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: Lol

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
}

task cl(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

class Lol implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project p) {
        def repositoriesConf = {
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
        }
        p.repositories(repositoriesConf)
    }
}
```

There're really many different ways of implementing this task. Pay attention to the fact that also `java` plugin will be needed and maybe the plugin you need to implement should apply `java` plugin as well.

Comment: @ChristianGoetze, does my answer solve the problem? If yes, please accept it.